# Convert bytes to string not working

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, encoding

I receive Array with bytes:

```
var requestPtr = [3, 64, 0, 73, 0, 110, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 110, 0, 97, 0, 108, 0, 32, 0, 70, 0, 108, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 104, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 47, 0, 48, 0, 120, 0, 48, 0, 56, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 47, 0, 48, 0, 52, 0, 42, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 54, 0, 75, 0, 103, 0, 44, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 42, 0, 48, 0, 54, 0, 52, 0, 75, 0, 103, 0, 44, 0, 48, 0, 55, 0, 42, 0, 49, 0, 50, 0, 56, 0, 75, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then remove first byte and convert array to string with this code:

```
requestPtr.remove(at: 0)

let nsdata = NSData(bytes: requestPtr, length: requestPtr.count)
var str = String(data: nsdata as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
```

If i do print in console it returns me string:
[image]
But i get weird encoding, when try to copy message.

[image]

And functions like `str.hasPrefix("@Internal Flash")` not working.

And `var tmp1 = description.components(separatedBy: ["/"])` returns:

```
["\u{03}@\0I\0n\0t\0e\0r\0n\0a\0l\0 \0F\0l\0a\0s\0h\0 \0 \0", "\00\0x\00\08\00\00\00\00\00\00\0", "\00\04\0*\00\01\06\0K\0g\0,\00\01\0*\00\06\04\0K\0g\0,\00\07\0*\01\02\08\0K\0g\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recevie array with byte, but only every second byte is correct

try this:

```
let test = String(requestPtr.enumerated().filter{ index, element in
    return index % 2 == 1
}.map { index, element in
    return Character(UnicodeScalar(element)! )
})
```

They are probably better solutions, but nothing comes to mind

Comment: thank you. Your solution works. Could you explain it please

Comment: i can try, but i need your function to recived bytes

Comment: i receive bytes from usb device: ```var request = IOUSBDevRequest(bmRequestType: 128, bRequest: 6, wValue: 0x300 | UInt16(index), wIndex: 0, wLength: 255, pData: &requestPtr, wLenDone: 255)
        
        kr = deviceInterface.DeviceRequest(deviceInterfacePtrPtr, &request)```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the data is encoded in UTF-16LE (little endian UTF-16), not in UTF-8.

(Code updated to clarify, with what data I have got the result shown.)

```
var requestPtr = [3, 64, 0, 73, 0, 110, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 110, 0, 97, 0, 108, 0, 32, 0, 70, 0, 108, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 104, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 47, 0, 48, 0, 120, 0, 48, 0, 56, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 47, 0, 48, 0, 52, 0, 42, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 54, 0, 75, 0, 103, 0, 44, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 42, 0, 48, 0, 54, 0, 52, 0, 75, 0, 103, 0, 44, 0, 48, 0, 55, 0, 42, 0, 49, 0, 50, 0, 56, 0, 75, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

requestPtr.remove(at: 0)

let data = Data(bytes: requestPtr.map{UInt8($0)})
var str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf16LittleEndian)!.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\0"))

debugPrint(str) //->"@Internal Flash  /0x08000000/04*016Kg,01*064Kg,07*128Kg"
```

(The actual data is said to be `[UInt8]`, but `.map{UInt8($0)}` is making it.)

Comment: how do you detect encoding? this doesn't work ```䀃䤀渀琀攀爀渀愀氀 䘀氀愀猀栀  ⼀　砀　㠀　　　　　　⼀　㐀⨀　㄀㘀䬀最Ⰰ　㄀⨀　㘀㐀䬀最Ⰰ　㜀⨀㄀㈀㠀䬀最```

Comment: UTF-16LE is one possible candidate to interpret your byte sequence. And please explain how you get  that _this doesn't work_ string.

Comment: @Arti, I have found it. You have tried my code without your `requestPtr.remove(at: 0)`. Please try my code after `requestPtr.remove(at: 0)`.

Comment: @Arti, and one more thing you should know, USB devices use UTF16LE encoding.

Comment: @Arti, then you are mistaking something. I'm very sure my code works when put after `var requestPtr = [...]` and `requestPtr.remove(at: 0)`. The output shown in my answer is taken from the actual output in the Playground.

Comment: yes it is weird, but i tried again. Same result... ```print(requestPtr)
        let data1 = Data(bytes: requestPtr.map{UInt8($0)})
        var str1 = String(data: data1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf16LittleEndian)!.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\0"))
        print(str1)```

Comment: Are you really using the `requestPtr` in your question? What does your `print(requestPtr)` output? Does it really show `[64, 0, 73, 0, 110, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 110, 0, 97, 0, ...]`? -- starting with `64` not with `3` nor `0`, OK?

Comment: @Arti, your pastebin code is different than mine and I do not understand what you want to tell me. First, I'll update my code to disambiguate, second, please test my updated code with Playground and see what you get. Let's talk about your actual full function after those two, OK?

Comment: oh, sorry, i copied old code. But i sent you code in comments that i used. It is not worked

Answer (score 1):

There is a need to define the byte array of type `[UInt8]`. Below mentioned will work and return `True`

`var requestPtr:[UInt8] = [3, 73, 110, 116, 101, 114, 110, 97, 108, 32, 70, 108, 97, 115, 104]
    requestPtr.remove(at: 0)
    print(requestPtr.count)
    print(requestPtr)
    let nsdata = NSData(bytes: requestPtr as [UInt8], length:    requestPtr.count)
    var str = String(data: nsdata as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    str.hasPrefix("Internal Flash")`

Comment: @Arti in your original code array is define with implicit type conversion due to which it's being converted differently when byte array is being converted to NSData. In my answer code byte array is explicitly defined as array of UInt8.